# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error when using angular.js routing module

Tags: angularjs

I want to try some simple example with angular.js routing. Here is my script:

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', []);

    sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider){
            $routeProvider.
                when('/AddNewOrder', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/add_order.html',
                    controller: 'AddOrderController'
                }).
                when('/ShowOrders', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/show_orders.html',
                    controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/AddNewOrder'
                });
        }]);

    sampleApp.controller('AddOrderController', function($scope){
        $scope.message = 'This is Add new order screen';
    });

    sampleApp.controller('ShowOrdersController', function($scope){
        $scope.message = 'This is Show orders screen';
    });
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <title>AngularJS Routing example</title>  

  <body ng-app="sampleApp">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
           <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#AddNewOrder"> Add New Order </a></li>
                <li><a href="#ShowOrders"> Show Order </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>

        </div>

    </div><!-- /.container -->

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

show_orders.html:

```
<h2>Show Orders</h2>
{{ message }}
```

add_order.html:

```
<h2>Add New Order</h2>
{{ message }}
```

When I click links in browser (Chrome) they don't open and I get this error in 'Network' tab:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run an http server in the back

in python for exmaple (from the directory of your project)

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Or turn your templates into script tags, for example

```
<script  type="text/ng-template" id="templates/add_order.html">
<h2>Add New Order</h2>
{{ message }}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using **Grunt** (http://gruntjs.com/) when developing AngularJS applications because it will:

1. Streamline your process
2. Facilitate testing, code validation and dependancy resolution
3. AND fix your problem, since it boots a small http server on port 9000. :)